# How to split numbers and text in MySQL

Tags: mysql, replace, regex

I have searched over the internet looking for a function like `REGEXP_REPLACE` in [**Oracle**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm), `regexp_replace` in [**PostgresSQL**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) but I haven't find one similar in MySQL just [**REGEXP**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) and **[RLIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)**, but these operators just check whether the string matches pattern containing a regular expression not what the match is.

I have read about UDF like [mysql-udf-regexp](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp), but it doesn't work for me since I want something that I can manipulate like `stored functions` for faster optimization tasks or whatever conditions I want.

My questions are:

- Do I have to make 2 functions if I want to delete all the `alpha characters` when I want just letters or vice versa?
- Does anyone know any better way to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everyone, but I'm going to use these `FUCNTIONs` that I made. One `FUNCTION` to extract *letters* and one to *extract* numbers (even decimals).

### Letters:

```
USE `test`;
DROP function IF EXISTS `alpha`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `test`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `alpha`(
vStr CHAR(75)) RETURNS char(32) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN 
    DECLARE vInd, vLen SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
    DECLARE vReturn CHAR(32) DEFAULT ''; 
    DECLARE vCharacter CHAR(1); 
    REPEAT 
    SET vLen = CHAR_LENGTH(vStr); 
    BEGIN 
        SET vCharacter = MID(vStr,vInd,1); 
        IF vCharacter REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]' THEN 
            SET vReturn=CONCAT(vReturn,vCharacter); 
        END IF; 
        SET vInd =vInd+1; 
    END; 
    UNTIL vInd > vLen END REPEAT; 
    RETURN vReturn; 
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

### Numerics/Digits:

```
USE `test`;
DROP function IF EXISTS `test`.`num`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `test`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `num`(
vStr CHAR(75)) RETURNS char(32) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN 
    DECLARE vInd, vLen SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
    DECLARE vReturn CHAR(32) DEFAULT ''; 
    DECLARE vCharacter CHAR(1); 
    REPEAT 
        SET vLen = CHAR_LENGTH(vStr); 
    BEGIN 
        SET vCharacter = MID(vStr,vInd,1); 
        IF vCharacter REGEXP '[[:digit:]|[:punct:]]' THEN 
            SET vReturn=CONCAT(vReturn,vCharacter); 
        END IF; 
        SET vInd =vInd+1; 
    END; 
    UNTIL vInd > vLen END REPEAT; 
    RETURN CAST(vReturn AS UNSIGNED); 
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a rather ugly approach that will strip alphanumeric characters from a user variable

## STRIPPING ALPHAS

```
SET @st='r1+o2l-3a4*n5d6o7';
SELECT (@st:=REPLACE(@st,ch,'')) FROM
(
    SELECT (x*10+y) ndx,SUBSTR(chars,x*10+y,1) ch FROM
    (SELECT 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' chars) L,
    (SELECT 0 x UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5 x UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) X,
    (SELECT 0 y UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5 x UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Y
    WHERE SUBSTR(chars,x*10+Y,1)<>'' ORDER BY SUBSTR(chars,x*10+y,1)
) alpha;
SELECT @st;
```

## STRIPPING ALPHAS EXECUTED

```
mysql> SELECT (@st:=REPLACE(@st,ch,'')) FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT (x*10+y) ndx,SUBSTR(chars,x*10+y,1) ch FROM
    ->     (SELECT 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' chars) L,
    ->     (SELECT 0 x UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    ->     UNION SELECT 5 x UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) X
    ->     (SELECT 0 y UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    ->     UNION SELECT 5 x UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Y
    ->     WHERE SUBSTR(chars,x*10+Y,1)<>'' ORDER BY SUBSTR(chars,x*10+y,1)
    -> ) alpha;
+---------------------------+
| (@st:=REPLACE(@st,ch,'')) |
+---------------------------+
| r1+o2l-34*n5d6o7          |
| r1+o2l-34*n5d6o7          |
| r1+o2l-34*n5d6o7          |
| r1+o2l-34*n56o7           |
| r1+o2l-34*n56o7           |
| r1+o2l-34*n56o7           |
| r1+o2l-34*n56o7           |
| r1+o2l-34*n56o7           |
| r1+o2l-34*n56o7           |
| r1+o2l-34*n56o7           |
| r1+o2l-34*n56o7           |
| r1+o2-34*n56o7            |
| r1+o2-34*n56o7            |
| r1+o2-34*56o7             |
| r1+2-34*567               |
| r1+2-34*567               |
| r1+2-34*567               |
| 1+2-34*567                |
| 1+2-34*567                |
| 1+2-34*567                |
| 1+2-34*567                |
| 1+2-34*567                |
| 1+2-34*567                |
| 1+2-34*567                |
| 1+2-34*567                |
| 1+2-34*567                |
+---------------------------+
26 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## STRIPPING ALPHAS RESULT

```
mysql> SELECT @st;
+------------+
| @st        |
+------------+
| 1+2-34*567 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## STRIPPING NUMERICS

```
SET @st='r1+o2l-3a4*n5d6o7';
SELECT (@st:=REPLACE(@st,ch,'')) FROM
(
    SELECT x+1 ndx,SUBSTR(chars,x+1,1) ch FROM
    (SELECT '0123456789' chars) L,
    (SELECT 0 x UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5 x UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) X
) numerics;
SELECT @st;
```

## STRIPPING NUMERICS EXECUTED

```
mysql> SET @st='r1+o2l-3a4*n5d6o7';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT (@st:=REPLACE(@st,ch,'')) FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT x+1 ndx,SUBSTR(chars,x+1,1) ch FROM
    ->     (SELECT '0123456789' chars) L,
    ->     (SELECT 0 x UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    ->     UNION SELECT 5 x UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) X
    -> ) numerics;
+---------------------------+
| (@st:=REPLACE(@st,ch,'')) |
+---------------------------+
| r1+o2l-3a4*n5d6o7         |
| r+o2l-3a4*n5d6o7          |
| r+ol-3a4*n5d6o7           |
| r+ol-a4*n5d6o7            |
| r+ol-a*n5d6o7             |
| r+ol-a*nd6o7              |
| r+ol-a*ndo7               |
| r+ol-a*ndo                |
| r+ol-a*ndo                |
| r+ol-a*ndo                |
+---------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## STRIPPING NUMERICS RESULT

```
mysql> SELECT @st;
+------------+
| @st        |
+------------+
| r+ol-a*ndo |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## STRIPPING ALPHANUMERICS

```
SET @st='r1+o2l-3a4*n5d6o7';
SELECT (@st:=REPLACE(@st,ch,'')) FROM
(
    SELECT (x*10+y) ndx,SUBSTR(chars,x*10+y,1) ch FROM
    (SELECT 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789' chars) L,
    (SELECT 0 x UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5 x UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) X,
    (SELECT 0 y UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5 x UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Y
    WHERE SUBSTR(chars,x*10+Y,1)<>'' ORDER BY SUBSTR(chars,x*10+y,1)
) alphanumeric;
SELECT @st;
```

## STRIPPING ALPHANUMERICS EXECUTED

```
mysql> SET @st='r1+o2l-3a4*n5d6o7';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT (@st:=REPLACE(@st,ch,'')) FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT (x*10+y) ndx,SUBSTR(chars,x*10+y,1) ch FROM
    ->     (SELECT 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789' chars) L,
    ->     (SELECT 0 x UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    ->     UNION SELECT 5 x UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) X,
    ->     (SELECT 0 y UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    ->     UNION SELECT 5 x UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Y
    ->     WHERE SUBSTR(chars,x*10+Y,1)<>'' ORDER BY SUBSTR(chars,x*10+y,1)
    -> ) alphanumeric;
+---------------------------+
| (@st:=REPLACE(@st,ch,'')) |
+---------------------------+
| r1+o2l-3a4*n5d6o7         |
| r+o2l-3a4*n5d6o7          |
| r+ol-3a4*n5d6o7           |
| r+ol-a4*n5d6o7            |
| r+ol-a*n5d6o7             |
| r+ol-a*nd6o7              |
| r+ol-a*ndo7               |
| r+ol-a*ndo                |
| r+ol-a*ndo                |
| r+ol-a*ndo                |
| r+ol-*ndo                 |
| r+ol-*ndo                 |
| r+ol-*ndo                 |
| r+ol-*no                  |
| r+ol-*no                  |
| r+ol-*no                  |
| r+ol-*no                  |
| r+ol-*no                  |
| r+ol-*no                  |
| r+ol-*no                  |
| r+ol-*no                  |
| r+o-*no                   |
| r+o-*no                   |
| r+o-*o                    |
| r+-*                      |
| r+-*                      |
| r+-*                      |
| +-*                       |
| +-*                       |
| +-*                       |
| +-*                       |
| +-*                       |
| +-*                       |
| +-*                       |
| +-*                       |
| +-*                       |
+---------------------------+
36 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## STRIPPING ALPHANUMERICS RESULT

```
mysql> SELECT @st;
+------+
| @st  |
+------+
| +-*  |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## EPILOGUE

This SELECT query is meant to hold up to 100 characters for stripping

You can replace `(SELECT 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789' chars) L,` with any list of characters you wish to strip from a user variable.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!